# IBM HATS Rational 9.6.0 problema con la vista previa WAS 8.5

Tags: ssl

Cuando mi compañera y yo realizamos la acción de vista previa en el programa IBM HATS. Aparece este error:

SSLC0008E: No se puede inicializar la conexión SSL. Se ha denegado el acceso no autorizado o los valores de seguridad han caducado. La excepción es javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message.

Dejo la descripción en inglés para si alguien de no habla española nos puede ayudar.

Comment: Hola, haz la descripción de tu problema en Español para evitar que tu pregunta sea borrada.

Comment: PD. Acá sólo se revisan preguntas en Español y se aceptan respuestas en Español. La versión inglesa la puedes eliminar.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo hemos solucionado. Al instalar la Herrramienta IBM HATS esta a de ser instalada en "Archivos de Programa". Además hay que ejecutar-lo(eclipe.exe) en modo administrador.